# Do you need a wildcard SSL cert for each sub-domain "level" you want to encrypt?

Tags: ssl-certificate

Assume I own **example.com** and I purchasd a wildcard SSL cert that works for ***.example.com**.  Management now wants to create "companion" sites to alreasy existing sites.  So if I have **foo.example.com** and **bar.example.com** they might also want me to create **meow.foo.example.com** and **woof.bar.example.com**.

The existing wildcard cert works for the sub-domain sites, as we've been doing all along.  I just learned it does NOT work for sub-sub-domain sites.  Is it possible to create a wildcard cert for ***.*.example.com**?

Would sub-sub-sub-domain's require an additional wildcard cert?  So if you want to protect X levels, do you need X certs?

Disclaimer: I spent a while researching this, but are a lot of seemingly conflicting questiona/answers on SO, so I feel bad about asking this again, but I don't want to go through the hassle of purchasing to find out later that I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10540/68042

you just need separate certificate for each level of subdomain, with names:

- example.com
- *.example.com
- *.*.example.com
- *.*.*.example.com

In theory, single certificate with all those entries in Subject Alt Name extension would do, but it may not work for some cases. Separate certificates are safer.

To use single certificate (for *.example.com) you may use names meow-foo.example.com instead of meow.foo.example.com

Comment: Are `..example.com` and `..*.example.com` valid? Would I be able to configure all subdomains of subdomains this way without having to define each one?

Answer (score 1):

While there may be some implementations which allow multiple wildcards, effectively the answer is **no, multiple wildcards are not allowed**.

RFC 6125 ([section 6.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3)) tries clarifying the common de facto rules, and distilled down to the core MUSTs the rules are effectively:

- If the first character is not `*` perform a literal match. (non-wildcard).
- If the second character is not `.` then match nothing (invalid wildcard)
- Find the first `.` in the match candidate, and literal-match starting with the second character in the dNSName value.

So `*.*.example.com` would not match `a.b.example.com` because `.*.example.com` != `.b.example.com`.

Of course, some clients may have implemented their matching logic differently. But counting on anything more lax than this interpretation will result in some clients saying it isn't a match when you were hoping it would.

(Okay RFC 6125 section 6.4.3 doesn't have any actual MUSTs; but if you respect the SHOULD NOTs and don't follow the MAY, but do support wildcard matching, you end up with the above.)

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Multi-domain wildcard SSL Certificate it will secure your sub-sub- domain.It can secure below wildcards

```
- *.mydomain.tld
- *.sub1.mydomain.tld
- *.sub2.mydomain.tld
- *.anydomain.com
```